# Jquery 1.4.4 and IE8 fails

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

Why does the following fall over on IE8 and not on IE10 and Firefox.

The error is Unexpected call to method of property access and happens on the prependTo(obj) line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    var myCurrentId = "btn_config_snippet_myAppName_myConfigName";

    textContainer =$('#configuration_container');
    $('<img id="'+ myCurrentId +'" src="images/myImage.png"></img>').prependTo(textContainer);

    obj = $('#' + myCurrentId);
    $('<div id="'+myCurrentId +'">FRED</div>').prependTo(obj);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='configuration_container'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are adding multiple elements with the same Id.  That is not supported and is probably causing your issues.

Comment: I am very very new to this and stuck doing support. I have changed the line to

     $('<div id="test_text">FRED</div>').prependTo(obj);

and still no joy